# Range of function $f(x)=\frac{x}{1-x^2}$

Tags: functions

How can we find the range of

$$f(x)=\frac{x}{1-x^2}?$$

From the quadratic formula, I found that the range is $\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}.$ However, the correct one is $\mathbb{R}.$

Comment: $f(0)=0{{{}}}$.

Comment: It would be most helpful to see your work on *how* you used the quadratic formula to deduce the range is $\mathbb{R}-\{0\}$.  Then you could get a pointed diagnosis as to where you went wrong.

Comment: If you have learned some calculus, using $\lim_{x\to1^-}f(x)=+\infty$ and $\lim_{x\to(-1)^+}f(x)=-\infty$ and the fact $f\in C(-1,1)$ can instantly deduce the range of $f$ is $\mathbb R$.

Comment: What I found is $x=-1\pm(1+4y^2)/2y.$ This means that $y\not=0.$

Comment: Try $$x=\tan t$$

Comment: You only use the quadratic formula on quaddtics.  If $y = 0$ than $yx^2 + x - k =0$ is not a quadratic.  It is a linear equation $x = 0$ which clearly has a solution of $x  = 0$.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose $y$ is in $\mathbb{R}$, and we wonder if $y$ is in the range. So we are wondering if there are $x$-values that solve $$y=\frac{x}{1-x^2}$$ Of course, $x$ will not be $1$ or $-1$ or the right side is undefined. The equation is equivalent to $$yx^2+x-y=0$$ Note it is still the case that $x$ could not be $1$ or $-1$.  We are still wondering if there are solutions in $x$ for our fixed value of $y$. Assuming $y\neq0$, this is a quadratic equation in $x$, and then there are solutions if and only if the discriminant is $\geq0$. The discriminant is $$1+4y^2$$ which is always $\geq1$. So no matter what nonzero value $y$ is, there is an $x$ (two actually) with $f(x)=y$. Now what if $y=0$ and the equation is not quadratic? Then trivially observe that $x=0$ solves the first equation.

In the end, nothing in $\mathbb{R}$ is excluded from the range.

Comment: Two usually, but yes. Nice.  +1

Comment: @Randall Not just "usually", but always. The discriminant here is always greater than $1$ (so it's nonzero).

Comment: I think I see what you were alluding to. I edited to handle $y=0$ separately.

Comment: What I found is $x=-1\pm(1+4y^2)/2y.$ This means that $y\not=0.$

Comment: @MasikKara But if $y=0$ you did not have a quadratic equation in the first place and should not have applied the quadratic formula.

Comment: SORRY. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 2):

A subtle aspect of the quadratic formula, that the solutions of $ax^2 + bx +c=0$ are $\frac {-b \pm {b^2 - 4ac}}{2a}$ are that in order to ***BE*** a quadratic, it is assumed that $a \ne 0$.

If $a$ *does* equal $0$ then what you have is $bx + c=0$ and that is *not* a quadratic; it's a *linear* equation and *its* root is $-\frac cb$.... (That is if it is assumed that $b \ne 0$.)

(To carry this idea to an extreme if $a=0$ and $b=0$ then you have $c=0$ and that's simply a statment that is true for all reals if $c =0$ and not true for any reals if $c \ne 0$.  So if $c \ne 0$ there are no "solutions".  If $c=0$ then all $x \in \mathbb R$ are "solutions" because $0=0$ for all $x$ [which have nothing to do the statement].  ... But I digress...)

So to solve for $\frac x{1-x^2} = y$ or $yx^2 + x - y = 0$ then solutions are:

$x = \frac {-1 \pm {1 + 4y^2}}{2y}$ if $y \ne 0$.  And that has  solutions for all $y\ne 0$.

*AND*

if $y = 0$ then the equation is $0x^2 + x -0 = 0$ or $x = 0$ and that has solution... $x = 0$ if $y = 0$.  And that *is* a solution for $y=0$.

So solutions exist for all $y$.

Answer (score 0):

Write it as:
$$f(x)=\frac x{1-x^2}=\frac12\left[\frac1{1-x}-\frac1{1+x}\right]=\frac12(g(x)-h(x)).$$
The function $g(x)$ is decreasing and ranges $(-\infty,0)\cup (0,\infty)$, $h(x)$ is increasing and ranges $(-\infty,0)\cup (0,\infty)$ and $f(0)=0$. Hence, $f(x)$ ranges $(-\infty,\infty)$.

Comment: But yoy are not sure that the function are continuous on $\mathbb{R}$ so how can you proceed?